# How to make my sitemap.xml open in the browser instead of trying to download the file in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, sitemap.xml

I want my sitemap.xml file to open in a browser window. But now it is loaded when you access it from the browser. How can this be configured in an ASP.Net Core project. I found similar information on Wordpress but don't know how it is done in ASP.Net Core.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /privacy
Disallow: /offer
Disallow: /warranty
Disallow: /payment
Disallow: /Catalog/Search
Disallow: /Catalog/Cart
Sitemap: https://someadress/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to browse your xml sitemap like "https://yourdomain.com/mysitemap.xml"

then you need to using **SEOHelper** library from AspNetCore in Startup.cs class in the project.
So :

1- create your sitemap.xml in **wwwroot** folder.

2- in Startup.cs `using AspNetCore.SEOHelper;`.

3- in Config() in Startup.cs `app.UseXMLSitemap(env.ContentRootPath);`